# Receive Single Data from xml

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have brought some data from the **server using ajax**.
Now I want to, not bring **all the data**, only the **nam**e is inter. 
How can I do this?
that my code

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'

const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response);
}
xhr.open('GET', url)
xhr.send()
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: I want to get the all user name out of all the information.

Comment: Please post *exactly* what sort of format you want, in an edit to your question, to make it clear - an array of names, or what?

Comment: If you want just the names of the users, there is no API on the site, which supports this feature. You need to manually map the data to get the names only. Have a look at [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: I'm writing here clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the xhr response and get the name of the users.

```
   xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
     if(xhr.response) {
       let userResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
       for (index in userResponse) {
           console.log(userResponse[index].name);
       }
     }
   }
```

You can even save it in a temporary variable and make further manipulations.

But if you meant bringing just the name from the server, it is not possible unless the server exposes an API to do so.

If you have access to the server you could create an API to do this. But, if your server had used graphQL, it is possible to make queries while making API requests like you asked for.

Comment: Now It's Working but showing error the top.                                                                               Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (index.js:7)

Comment: That is because the xhr response will be empty until the response is received. That is why you were getting errors initially. I've added an extra check to validate that. Please try now. Accept the answer if it has solved the issue.

Comment: yes your answer is useful for me and resolve my problem what did i wanted.definitely i accept the answer.you also vote my question if want.